# Writing for loop outputs to CSV columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a for loop that prints 4 details:

```
deats = soup.find_all('p')
    for n in deats:
        print n.text
```

The output is 4 printed lines.

Instead of printing, what I'd like to do is have each 'n' written to a different column in a .csv. Obviously, when I use a regular .write() it puts it in the same column. In other words, how would I make it write each iteration of the loop to the next column?

Comment: use writerow() from csv as I have suggested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei, try like this:

```
import csv

csv_output = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))   # output.csv is the output file name!
csv_output.writerow(["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"]) # Setting first row with all column titles

temp = []
deats = soup.find_all('p')
for n in deats:
    temp.append(str(n.text))
csv_output.writerow(temp)
```

Comment: Hi S.M. so, I'm a little confused by this. Does this add a new row before writing?

Comment: yes, it does! If you don't need that, then remove this line:
 
    csv_output.writerow(["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"]) # Setting first row with all column titles

Comment: sure, but suppose that the deats loop is nested inside of another for loop. What happens when I get to the deats loop again? Is it possible to set it up to add a new to start writing the next iteration?

Comment: to add a new row? you mean?

Comment: Yes. so, imagine:
ln 1: for x in range(1,4) ln 2:name = "Joe" ln3 for n in deats ln4 print n.text
I'd want to not only put the deats into the row, but also name. and this is going to happen 3 times because of the for loop at the top. So, for each iteration of the loop, I'll need a new row added, and I'll need to write to that row.

Comment: For each row, manage a list. you can use append/extend whatever you like! then use writerow() to insert the row all together. Sounds good? Also, if you think my answer is correct, then you can accept this as a correct answer too!

Answer (score 2):

You would create the csv row as a loop (or using list comprehension) I will show the explicit loop for ease of reading and you can change it to a single list comprehension line yourself.

```
row = []
for n in deats:
  row.append(n)
```

Now you have row ready to write to the .csv file using csv.Writer()

Answer (score 1):

```
extra_stuff = pie,cake,eat,too
some_file.write(",".join(n.text for n in deats)+"," + ",".join(str(s) for s in extra_stuff))
```

??? is that all you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, this works. I'm embarrassed. Maybe this is a little harder: suppose that, in addition to the n deats, I also want to write 5 other things to the same row? Can I do that in a single line of python? The other variables are, say, "pie", "cake", "eat", "too".

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this will not handle the cases where `n.text` contains commas or newlines.  That is why everyone else is recommending the `csv` module.

Comment: sure worth noting ... 9/10 times i find the csv module to be overkill for this sort of thing (although for html content maybe not)

Comment: Hmm, I get a type error because the function only takes 1 argument but 3 are given. I should clarify, pie = "pie" and I'd like to write pie to the next column. I think that ...for n in deats) + pie) returns the error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: no its because your trying to do `..n in deats) + pie,cake,etc...` see the commas that are being interpretted as extra arguments... I edited my answer to address your variables you wnat to tack on

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Don't forget the comma between the `deats` stuff and the `extra_stuff`. It's starting to get to the point where it might be more readable to build a single combined list before doing any joins.

Comment: @JohnY thanks :) good catch ... and good suggestion ... but meh :P

Answer (score 1):

You use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for this:

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    opwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=','
    opwriter.writerow([n.text for n in deats])
```